# Como acessar o nome de uma instância de classe para poder usar posteriormente?

Tags: python

Estou com uma dúvida de como usar o "NOME" de uma instância de classe. Se eu a declaro diretamente:

```
Sala_10 = Sala("Sala_10")
```

funciona bem. Posso usar o `Sala_10.método()`, mas eu gostaria de criar (instanciar) as salas através de uma função, chamada `add_sala(id)`.

Eu até crio a sala normal, mas não sei como referenciar essa sala... claro, recebo a mensagem de erro:

> NameError: name 'Sala_10' is not defined

meu código vai abaixo, obrigado!

**teste-myclass.py**

```
salas = []

class Sala:

    def __init__(self, id):

        self.id = id

        self.alunos = []  # lista de alunos da sala.

    def add_alunos(self, num, nome):
        nome = Aluno(num, nome)  # -> cria o objeto ALUNO
        self.alunos.append(nome)


class Aluno:
    def __init__(self, num, nome):
        self.num = num
        self.nome = nome


def add_sala(id):  # função para criar e adicionar SALAS
    nome = Sala(id)  # cria uma nova sala chamada: o valor da variável x
    salas.append(nome)
```

Quando faço:

```
Sala_9A = Sala("Sala_9A")
Sala_9A.add_alunos(1, "Austregésilo de Athayde")
print(Sala_9A.alunos[0].nome)
```

Funciona ok, mas se fizer:

```
add_sala("Sala_9B")

for i in range(len(salas)):
    print(salas[i].id)
```

Não funciona! Como usar a referência passada abaixo como o nome do objeto para invocá-lo depois?

Agora vou usar a sala `Sala_9B` criada pela Função `add_sala()`
como fazer para usar acessar corretamente essa instância da classe Sala ?

```
Sala_9B.add_alunos(1, "Sepúlveda Pertence")
print(Sala_9B.alunos[0].nome)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/bueno/Programming/Programa_Conselho/exemplos-ajuda/teste-myclass.py", line 44, in 
>       Sala_9B.add_alunos(1, "Sepúlveda Pertence")
>   NameError: name 'Sala_9B' is not defined

Comment: Tente ao máximo aplicar as formatações que o editor lhe fornece. Tem tanto o botão para formatar o código, com o de citações que será apropriado para mensagens de erro. Tendo em conta que troquei muita coisa, veja como ficou a pergunta, e se reflete a sua duvida original.

Comment: Referente à questão, se a instancia foi criada dentro do `add_sala` então não ficou com nenhuma variável que a referencie. Por isso tem de aceder a partir da lista de salas mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Sua classe Sala parece meio preguiçosa ou "inútil", já que ela só serve para adicionar alunos, talvez seja uma saída melhor usar um dicionário e ter como chave o nome da sala.
Algo como isso:

```
salas = {}

class Aluno:
    def __init__(self, num, nome):
        self.num = num
        self.nome = nome

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


def add_sala(id_sala):  # função para criar e adicionar SALAS
    if id_sala not in salas:
        salas[id_sala] = []  # cria uma nova sala com o nome passado em id_sala
    else:
        print('Sala já existente!')

def add_alunos(num, nome, id_sala): # -> Melhor seria passar o aluno já criado para diminuir o acoplamento
    nome = Aluno(num, nome)  # -> cria o objeto ALUNO
    salas[id_sala].append(nome)

add_sala('Sala-B9') # -> adiciona nova sala
print(salas.keys()) # -> mostra salas existentes
print(salas['Sala-B9']) # -> mostra alunos da sala apontada
add_alunos(10, 'Matheus', 'Sala-B9') # -> adiciona aluno a Sala-B9
print(salas['Sala-B9'][0]) # -> mostra o primeiro aluno na Sala-B9
# pode ser feito um for para todos os alunos assim: for aluno in salas['Sala-B9']: ...
add_sala('Sala-B9') # -> tentando adicionar sala já existente, a sala não é sobrescrita
add_sala('Sala-A10') # -> adiciona outra sala
print(salas.keys()) # -> mostra salas existentes
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, concordo com vc, que meu exemplo está bastante reduzido (é que eu suprimi várias outras funcionalidades da classe, como alterar dados dos alunos, etc, e mais algumas etapas que ainda vou adicionar). Vou considerar sua sugestão de usar dicionários... muito válido. Mas, caso eu siga com minha ideia original, insisto em perguntar se é possível aceder aos métodos da classe se ela for criada por meio da função add_sala(), ou somente acessando a lista salas[] ?  O que já estou fazendo e está funcionando bem....

Comment: Esta é a resposta certa - se você tem um número fixo de salas, que vão ser acessadas individualemente para coisas diferentes em pontos do programa, você associa as mesmas a variáveis - e aí você cria uma por uma no seu código de forma explícita. Se você vai criar salas dinamicamente, e precisa só de um identificador para chegar na mesma sala, o correto é usar um dicionário - nesse caso o identificador da sala é só mais um _dado_ , não é parte do código.  
Não precisa nem da função - pode fazer uma dict-comprehension do tipo:
`salas = {f"sala_{i:02d}": Sala(i)  for i in range(10)} `

Comment: Talvez essa modelagem não seja muito fácil de perceber, pois a sua ideia é que uma sala se auto gerencie, o que não acontece na vida real. Alguém, diferente dos objetos aluno e sala, gera uma relação entre esses dois, tornando possível que eles interajam entre si. Se sua ideia realmente for usar uma classe que seja responsável por relacionar alunos e salas, irei linkar um código para que possa dar uma olhada, se, no seu modelo, sua classe Sala realmente possui comportamentos próprios de um objeto Sala, então pode adaptar o que precisar. [link](https://pastebin.com/aaXMgzN5)